# How to define that a binary variable is 1 or 0 according to my conditions?

Tags: python, linear-programming, gurobi

For example, if my (binary) decision variable is `X` and I want it to take the value `1` when I program something and `0` if I do not, how is it done in python + gurobi?

```
X = model.addVar(vtype="GRB.BINARY", name = "x1")
```

Comment: What do you mean with "program something"? Could you give an example of what your conditions are?

Comment: You mean set the default value to zero?

Answer (score -2):

Set the variable manually using a constraint.

```
programmed_input = 0 # or 1 if needed
m.addConstr(X[i]==programmed_input)
```